# How to changing a style in node_modules in its own vue <style> tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, node-modules

I want to make changes to the css file inside the multiselect package. But I don't want to change it from within node_modules, all I want is to write it between style tags of my page that I created with vue. I want to change the white-space property But I can't see any change when I write as below. Can you help with this?

Default.css (Node_modules)

```
.multiselect-tag {
    align-items: center;
    background: var(--ms-tag-bg,#10b981);
    border-radius: var(--ms-tag-radius,4px);
    color: var(--ms-tag-color,#fff);
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

My template

```
<template>
  <div class="filters">
    <Multiselect
      class="multiselect"
      v-model="value"
      mode="tags"
      placeholder="Customer"
      :close-on-select="false"
      :filter-results="false"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

My CSS code

```
<style scoped>  
.multiselect {
  --ms-tag-bg: #dbeafe;
  --ms-tag-color: #2563eb;
  --ms-radius: 0.475rem;
  --ms-dropdown-radius: 0.475rem;
  --ms-spinner-color: #2563eb;
  --ms-tag-ml: 0.85rem;
}
.multiselect,
.multiselect-tag {
  white-space: normal !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove the `scoped` from your `<style scoped>` style tag, as this will let the styles only apply for the current component (and the root node of the child). But you want to style an element the Multiselect component.

```
<style>  
.multiselect {
  --ms-tag-bg: #dbeafe;
  --ms-tag-color: #2563eb;
  --ms-radius: 0.475rem;
  --ms-dropdown-radius: 0.475rem;
  --ms-spinner-color: #2563eb;
  --ms-tag-ml: 0.85rem;
}
.multiselect,
.multiselect-tag {
  white-space: normal !important;
}
</style>
```

Beware that removing the scoped will make the styles apply globally, so all Multiselect instances will be affected. If this is not what you need, you might try to use deep selectors.

See [vue style docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So if I have got you right, you want to change / overwrite your default CSS from your stylesheet with new values in your hmtl.

To do this, simply insert "style" within your tag.

For example:

```
<Multiselect class="multiselect" style="color: black;"/>
```

Comment: it doesn't work cause i want to change the multiselect tag part of the action i want to do

Comment: I am quite not sure, what you want to do exactly. You want to overwrite the values for class .multiselect-tag from default.css with the values from your CSS code?

Comment: yeah exactly, but I want to make changes in the multiselect-tag class I want to make. I want to write this change between the <style></style> tag in the vue template.

Comment: okay, I haven't tried this at the moment, but have you already tried to set an "!important" after your changes? It sounds a bit like the default css is "superior" to the changes you do in your CSS code. I will edit my answer with an example

Comment: thanks for help. Please check top of answers, removing the scoped property worked